# hta/ javascript How to execute an application with relative path

Tags: javascript, html, wsh, hta

I'm building a .hta (with javascript) from which i want to launch several applications.

But when i execute my .hta i get the error message can't find file

this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile(path) {
    var relpath = window.location.href;
    var fullpath = relpath + path;

    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run(fullpath, 1, false);
    }

    RunFile("\file.exe");
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.location.href` includes filename and protocol too. Try this:

```
var relpath = window.location.pathname.replace(/\\/g,'/').split('/');
relpath.pop();// JScript: relpath.length = relpath.length - 1;
relpath = relpath.join('/') + '/';
```

Notice use of `/` instead `\`, and it's also handy to end up `relpath` with `/`, so you don't need to add it to function argument.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what you mean with getting location without file, maybe this (citation from Windows Sripting Technologies (unfortunately broken now):

```
"The CurrentDirectory returns a string that contains the fully qualified path of
the current working directory of the active process."
```

The active process is for example the running HTA, so this will give the local path of the HTA file (without filename).

`currentDirectory` is a property of `WScript.Shell`, so you can use it with `WshShell` in your code, also to set working directory.

Comment: is there a way to get the location without the file itself?

Comment: Ehh... My code does just that. Or do you mean to get a path without `window.location` object?

Comment: Thank you very much your piece of code works, but when i put spaces in the map names instead of _, i get the same error.

Comment: Enclose the whole path string into double quotes like this: `var path = '"' + fullpath + '"';`. To answer to your last comment, there's no such of property in `location` object.